# S7.Net read negative value from Siemens S7-1500 get wrong value

Tags: c#, siemens

I'm using S7.net to communicate with S7-1500 PLC.  One of the value set in the plc is -90, when I read this value using code below, it show 65570 in winforms instead of -90.

```
var data = (ushort)plc.Read("DB10.DBW100");
```

The type set in plc program is "ShortToSignedWord".

How I can get the -90 and show in winforms?

Comment: `ShortToSignedWord` has a range of `-32768...+3276` whereas `ushort` goes from 0...65535. Are you sure you're using the right conversion?

Comment: Thanks for the guide, finally found need convertoShort after cast using "ushort"       var data = ((ushort)plc.Read("DB10.DBW100")).ConvertToShort();